# Given an array of size y, containing arrays of size n, how can I return all logical combinations using Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

What I want to do is deal with *n* sets, while the code I provide below works with exactly 4 sets.

```
def show_combinations
  @combos = []
  ['A', 'no A'].each do |a|
    ['B', 'no B'].each do |b|
      ['C', 'no C'].each do |c|
        ['D', 'no D'].each do |d|
          @combos << [a, b, c, d]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**How can I refactor this following code to deal with the following scenario:
Given I have an array of size y containing arrays of size n, I want to return all the combinations.** It's important to note that only one item in each of the sub arrays can be in the results. (Such as "Completed Profile" can't also be in the results with "Not completed profile")

Background:

A user might have some tasks: for example, "Complete Profile" or "Set Up Email" or whatever. Those tasks can be represented like this:

```
@task_states = [["Completed Profile, NOT Completed Profile"], ["Set up Email", "NOT set up Email"]]
```

Then, passing @task_states into the method, the results should be this:

```
[
["Completed Profile", "Set up Email"],
["Completed Profile", "NOT set up Email"],
["NOT Completed Profile", "Set up Email"],
["NOT Completed Profile", "NOT Set up Email"]
]
```

So an array of arrays representing all the combinations. Obviously "Completed Profile" can't also be in the same array as "NOT Completed Profile," etc.

Thanks!

Comment: [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-combination) or [Array#repeated_combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination) any good?

Comment: Do you mean the cartesian product of the arrays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you want to compute the cartesian product of the arrays. The method which computes the cartesian product is (not too surprisingly) called [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
@task_states.first.product(*@task_states.drop(1))
```

So, for example:

```
['A', 'no A'].product(['B', 'no B'], ['C', 'no C'], ['D', 'no D'])
#=> [[   "A",    "B",    "C",    "D"],
#    [   "A",    "B",    "C", "no D"],
#    [   "A",    "B", "no C",    "D"],
#    [   "A",    "B", "no C", "no D"],
#    [   "A", "no B",    "C",    "D"],
#    [   "A", "no B",    "C", "no D"],
#    [   "A", "no B", "no C",    "D"],
#    [   "A", "no B", "no C", "no D"],
#    ["no A",    "B",    "C",    "D"],
#    ["no A",    "B",    "C", "no D"],
#    ["no A",    "B", "no C",    "D"],
#    ["no A",    "B", "no C", "no D"],
#    ["no A", "no B",    "C",    "D"],
#    ["no A", "no B",    "C", "no D"],
#    ["no A", "no B", "no C",    "D"],
#    ["no A", "no B", "no C", "no D"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

By all means, use [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-product), but as in oft the case with Ruby, there are other ways. Here are two.

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

**Use math to compute each of the `arr.size**arr.first.size` combinations**

```
def cartesian_product(arr)
  n, m = arr.size, arr.first.size
  (0..n**m-1).map do |x|
    (n-1).downto(0).map do |i|
      x, r = x.divmod(m)
      arr[i][r]
    end.reverse
  end
end

cartesian_product arr
  #=> [[1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9],
  #    [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9],
  #    [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 9],
  #    [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8], [2, 6, 9],
  #    [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 4, 9], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 9],
  #    [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

**Use recursion**

```
def cartesian_product(arr)
  first, *rest = arr
  return first.map { |o| [o] } if rest.empty?
  c = cartesian_product(rest)
  first.flat_map { |o| c.map { |a| [o] + a } }
end

cartesian_product arr
  #=> same as above
```

In this application each element (array) of `arr` contains no duplicates. In other situations, where duplicates may be present (and where the products returned are not to contain duplicates), one should first compute

```
arr_without_dups = arr.map(&:uniq)
```

and then calculate the combinations from `arr_without_dups`.

Answer (score 1):

While the answers provided were great and Jörg's is the one I accepted, I wanted to share the answer that one of my friends provided me in case anyone else encounters this question. Essentially it's Jörg's answer but with a bit more depth.

**Cartesian products**
What you are asking for is called the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and it's already built in with [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-product).

For example:

```
[0, 1].product([0, 1])
# => [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Notice that this gives us all possible 2-bit numbers, from 00-11

You can give Array#product any number of arrays:

```
[0, 1].product([0, 1], [0, 1])
# => [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Notice that this gives us all the possible 3-bit numbers, from 000-111.

**Your problem**
Looking at your exact problem:

```
["A", "no A"].product(["B", "no B"], ["C", "no C"], ["D", "no D"])
=> [["A", "B", "C", "D"],
 ["A", "B", "C", "no D"],
 ["A", "B", "no C", "D"],
 ["A", "B", "no C", "no D"],
 ["A", "no B", "C", "D"],
 ["A", "no B", "C", "no D"],
 ["A", "no B", "no C", "D"],
 ["A", "no B", "no C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "B", "C", "D"],
 ["no A", "B", "C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "B", "no C", "D"],
 ["no A", "B", "no C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "C", "D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "no C", "D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "no C", "no D"]]
gives you all the possible combinations from "ABCD" to "noA noB noC noD"
```

**Generic solution**
We can make this work with any generic array of arrays by leveraging the splat * operator.

```
def combinations(arrays)
  first, *rest = arrays
  first.product(*rest)
end
```

Then we can say:

```
arrays_to_combine = [["A", "no A"], ["B", "no B"], ["C", "no C"], ["D", "no D"]]
combinations(arrays_to_combine)
=> [["A", "B", "C", "D"],
 ["A", "B", "C", "no D"],
 ["A", "B", "no C", "D"],
 ["A", "B", "no C", "no D"],
 ["A", "no B", "C", "D"],
 ["A", "no B", "C", "no D"],
 ["A", "no B", "no C", "D"],
 ["A", "no B", "no C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "B", "C", "D"],
 ["no A", "B", "C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "B", "no C", "D"],
 ["no A", "B", "no C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "C", "D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "C", "no D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "no C", "D"],
 ["no A", "no B", "no C", "no D"]]
```

Special thanks to Joel Quenneville of [Thoughtbot](https://upcase.com) for helping me with this as well as the rest of the people who provided answers.