# How to recursively find permutations of two dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have an array with elements that are arrays of varying sizes. For example:

```
[[3],[11,2],[11,2],[3]]
```

I would like to find permutations of all of the individual items in the nested arrays. For the array above, I'd like a return value of:

```
[
  [3, 11, 11, 3],
  [3, 11, 2, 3],
  [3, 2, 11, 3],
  [3, 2, 2, 3]
]
```

I have a solution that works, but it seems particularly long-winded:

```
array = [[3],[11,2],[11,2],[3]]
array.product(*array).map { |e| e.drop(1) }.uniq
```

How should I implement a recursive approach to this, and how would that work? I am having trouble wrapping my head around this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conventional way of solving this problem is to use the methods [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Array#drop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-drop).

```
arr = [[3], [11,2], [11,2,7], [4]]

arr.first.product(*arr.drop(1))
  #=> [[3, 11, 11, 4], [3, 11, 2, 4], [3, 11, 7, 4],
  #    [3, 2, 11, 4], [3, 2, 2, 4], [3, 2, 7, 4]]
```

If any element of `arr` contains duplicates the return value will also contain duplicates. If duplicates are not wanted, use

```
arr.map(&:uniq).first.product(*arr.drop(1))
```

The asker has, however, requested a recursive solution. That could be written as follows:

```
def prod(arr)
  return arr if arr.size == 1
  t = prod(arr.drop(1))
  arr.first.flat_map { |x| t.map { |a| [x] + a } }
end

prod arr
  #=> [[3, 11, 11, 4], [3, 11, 2, 4], [3, 11, 7, 4],
  #    [3, 2, 11, 4], [3, 2, 2, 4], [3, 2, 7, 4]]
```

Comment: I cannot decide whether this is a dupe or not. The answer is identical, at least: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43748139/2988

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I'd call it a dup. In fact, it's probably a dup many times over.

Comment: I am looking for recursion. This answer doesn't show recursion, so it is not an answer to my question nor is it a dupe of the above link.

Comment: @Jörg pondered whether the question--not my answer--was a dup. In my experience, when the asker stipulates a particular approach for solving a problem, it generally means that he/she has assumed--perhaps incorrectly--that the stated approach must be used to solve the problem. (It's so common that there is a name for it: an [x-y problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).) For that reason, (as here) readers often provide what they regard as the best solution to the problem, regardless of whether it employs the stated approach. (cont.)

Comment: ...You certainly can ask for a solution that employs a particular approach. I have edited my answer to show how recursion could be used.

Answer (score 1):

**Initialization:**

```
@arr = [[3],[11,2],[11,2],[3]]
@perms = []
```

**Function Definition:**

```
def recursion(idx, temp = [])
    if (idx == @arr.size) then @perms.push(temp.clone); return end
    @arr[idx].each { |x|  recursion(idx+1, temp << x); temp.pop }
end
```

**Call :**

```
recursion(0)
p @perms
 => [[3, 11, 11, 3], [3, 11, 2, 3], [3, 2, 11, 3], [3, 2, 2, 3]]
```